# C program to find bell's numbers using factorial calculation

Tags: c

I need help with my program which I think is almost there. I'm going off the equation {n k} = n! / k!(n – k)!. I'm not sure if I'm calculating it properly. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

I'm not sure if declaring my factorial function as a float is messing anything up but the compiler kept giving me a warnings until I changed this to a float

```
float factorial(float num)
{
    float result = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i < num; i ++)
        result *= i;

    return result;    
}
```

In the bells function I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with n over k on the left side of the equation.

```
void bells(int n) 
{

    float sum = 1;
    //printing bells first number
    printf("Bell Number [0] = 1\n");
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("Bell Number [%d] = %.0lf\n", i, sum);
        sum += factorial(n) / (factorial(i)*factorial(n - i));
    }

}
```

main is working fine

```
 int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int restart = 1;

    //while is used to restart program on users request
    while(restart == 1)
    {
        int userNum;
        printf("Enter a number :");
        scanf("%d",&userNum);

        bells(userNum);

        //Restarting program on users request 
        printf("\nRestart program? (1 = yes : 0 = no) ");
        scanf("%d", &restart);

    }//end of restart while

}//end of main
```

Sample output:

Bell Number [0] = 1

Bell Number [1] = 1

Bell Number [2] = 20

Bell Number [3] = 362

Bell Number [4] = 3269

Bell Number [5] = 18773

Bell Number [6] = 76913

Bell Number [7] = 239705

Bell Number [8] = 592421

Bell Number [9] = 1197077

Bell Number [10] = 2028479

Comment: I switched everything to integers and the factorial is working properly. My issue is the equation I cannot find anything that makes sense to me.

Comment: You can only store up to 12! in a 32-bit integer; you can only store up to 20! in a 64-bit integer.  You get to overflow very quickly if you are not very careful.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the binomial coefficient (n k) with the Stirling number {n k}. If you want to use the binomial coefficient summation formula, then use the first formula referenced here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Summation_formulas

If you want to use the Stirling summation formula, then use the second formula.

I'd advise using ints and not floats as these numbers are defined to be integers.

Also, check your factorial function. 2! = 2. Your function returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

//If I were you, I would rather use the recursive way for factorials
//Moreover, factorials are always positive and are big numbers, which means it will be better to use unsigned integers, and long ones
unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long num)
{
    if(num < 2)
        return 1;

    return num*factorial(num-1);
}

//More handy to have a binomial function ;)
unsigned long long binomial(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long k)
{
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k));
}

//From wikipedia : "The Bell numbers satisfy a RECCURRENCE relation involving binomial coefficients"
unsigned long long bell(int n)
{
    if(!n) return 1; // same as if(n == 0), this is the stop condition of the reccurrence

    unsigned long long sum = 0;

    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        sum += binomial(n-1, k) * bell(k); //recursive function as you can see

    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int restart = 1, userNum;

    //Better not "restart == 1" when looping like this ;) In fact, it will keep looping while "restart" is different from 0
    while(restart)
    {
        printf("Enter a positive number :");
        scanf("%d",&userNum);

        printf("The %ith number is : %llu\n", userNum, bell(userNum-1));

        printf("Restart program? (1 = yes : 0 = no) ");
        scanf("%d", &restart);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT : If you're tired of writing "unsigned long long", you can create a new type using one of the two methods :

```
#define fat_int unsigned long long

typedef unsigned long long fat_int;
```

Comment: Why recursion?  There's a moderate chance the optimizer will convert the tail recursion into a loop, but a loop is simpler.  You've not directly mentioned the problems of overflow.  Even 64-bit `unsigned long long` can only store values up to 20!.

Comment: imo, recursion is easier to read, this is more beautiful code and can sometimes be more efficient ! You're right about int overflows, the best way of doing that would probably be using strings to compute large integers (with libraries such as GMP) but it looks like this guy is a beginner and won't bother with such library ! unsigned long long (or uint64_t) is probably the best alternative....

Comment: Beauty, then, is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Thank you for the help I have leaned a lot from all the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is was trying to do so I figured I would post it. Thanks for all the help it's working perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>


long long int factorial(long long int num)
{
    long long int result = 1;

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= num ; i ++)
        result *= i;

    return result;  
}



long long int binomial(long long int n, long long int k)
{
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k));
}

long long int bell(int n)
{
    if(!n)  
        return 1;


    long long int sum = 0;

    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        sum += binomial(n-1, k) * bell(k);

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int restart = 1, userNum;

    while(restart)
    {
        printf("Enter the value of n:");
        scanf("%d",&userNum);

        for(int i = 1; i <= userNum; i++)
            printf("Bell Number [%d] = %lli\n", i, bell(i-1));

        printf("Restart program? (1 = yes : 0 = no) ");
        scanf("%d", &restart);
    }

}
```